# How to get all the dependencies of a .deb onto a disk?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, apt-get, deb, dpkg

I have a situation where I'll need to install a few .deb archives onto a number of Ubuntu systems, but the systems I'll be installing onto have no internet access, and as such, apt-get won't be able to "get" anything.

I know that all of the systems in question will have been fully updated at least to the basic Ubuntu "Precise Pangolin" release (64-bit x86 version), but beyond that I don't know exactly what is or is not installed.

So, my thinking was I could just install a bare-bones Precise Pangolin system, and then burn to a DVD (or two) all the .deb packages that apt-get decides to install when it needs to satisfy the dependencies of my stuff.

Is there some straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is: `apt-offline`

There is a good explanation for how it works [here](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/648/Offline_Package_Management_for_APT).